# Openerp custom report error - can only parse strings

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I created openerp custom report, but when I try to open it, I'm getting this error:

can only parse strings

```
(<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>, ValueError(u'can only parse strings',), <traceback object at 0x28c908c0>)
```

Does anyone know what that means and where could be the problem? I read that it may be something wrong with rml file name or path to it. I checked it, but it seems its correct.

So no one knows any ideas what could such error mean?

Comment: show us the code also along with the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bypassed this installing report without translation file and after that I intalled translation file using administration menu. As for now that is the only method I managed to print this report.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your report definitions and call scripts. Most probably you have a mismatch in your "report.RML" name or path to the RML file.

If it doesnt solve your issue please show your python and xml code

Comment: I found the problem. It has something to do with translation file. If I deleted translation file, report started to work. Don't know what is wrong with translation file. I used it in other modules and didn't give such error.

Comment: Maybe, In your translation file you will be using some characters, that are not encoded by the current encoder. You can try by removing the language from report and create your report in the language you want to use.